# Why does the program run only once

Tags: python, c, tcp

I have write server and client programs for experiment. I want achieve that effect: once server transfer "HELLO", the client w receive it and send back "HELLO FROM WIN" and wait for the next information. However, the server only get the first response and the client crushed(shutdown a few seconds later), Some codes are below.

client.c

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
char receive[6] = "";
char *send = "HELLO FROM WIN";

startupWSA();
SOCKET sock = createTCPSocket();
    
while(1){
    recv(sock,receive,6,0);
    
    printf("%s\n",payload);
    printf("%s\n",receive);
    memset(receive,'\0',6);

    sendto(sock,send,16,0,(const struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    memset(send,'\0',16);

}
}
```

server.py

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 5555
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('socket is ready')

connectionSocket,addr = serverSocket.accept()
while True:
    send = input('>')
    connectionSocket.send(send.encode())
    receive = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(receive)
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: If the client dies, that would explain your server only getting 1 response.

Comment: The string you receive in the C program will very likely not be null-terminated, which means you can go out of bounds when you print it.

Comment: And why do you do `memset(send,'\0',16);`?

Comment: You cant use `sendto` with TCP sockets, please use `send`

Comment: Also, your local variable `send` is hiding the `send` function from the sockets library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *send = "HELLO FROM WIN";
```

That's a pointer to a read-only string literal. In C you are allowed to have a non-const pointer to it (until C11 I believe), but you still cannot write to it. You try to do this here:

```
memset(send,'\0',16);
```

This is undefined behavior so crashing is a definite possibility (and a good one, too - much better than "working" until you deploy your code to production!)

To get around it you can change `send` to be an array with automatic storage:

```
char send[] = "HELLO FROM WIN";
```

And to make sure you don't write out of bounds:

```
sendto(sock,send,sizeof(send),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr));
memset(send, '\0', sizeof(send));
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
 char *send = "HELLO FROM WIN";
```

You declare `send` as a pointer and initialzs it to point to the **constant string literal**  "HELLO FROM WIN".

That constant will in general be somewhere in a read only memory region, so wehn you try to overweite it with `memset()` your program crashes.

Declare it as an array by:

```
 char send[16] = "HELLO FROM WIN";
```

or

```
 char send[] = "HELLO FROM WIN";
```

But in the latter case, the array size would only be 15 so your `memset()` still could crash